# Extract the word containing this index

Tags: code-golf, string

For this challenge, a word is defined as a string of letters, separated by spaces.

Given a string of words, and an integer `i` representing an index into that string, output the whole word which contains the character at index `i`.

For example (using 0-based indexing), with the string `code golf`, and the index `6`, the 7th character is the `o` (`code golf`), so the output is the word `golf`.

You may use 0- or 1-based indexing, and you may assume the index `i` is in range, and does not point to a space.

You may assume the string:

- is non-empty
- contains only lowercase ASCII letters and spaces
- contains no consecutive spaces
- does not start or end with a space

### Test cases

0-indexed.

```
index   string                   output
-----------------------------------------
0       w                        w
6       a e i o u                o
6       code golf                golf
17      red lorry yellow lorry   lorry
8       avuncular                avuncular
```